# Backbone groupBy two views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two views, I am trying to use `groupBy` to group the players to the team they are on this is defined in the model obviously. I am just confused on rendering some markup let me show you some code

**Player view for a single player:**

```
    //Player view for a single player (just the render method)
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    }
```

**Players view for a collection of players:**

```
    //Players view for a collection of players (just the render method)
    render: function() {
        var groupedPlayers = _.groupBy(playersCollection.models, function(player) { return player.get('team') });

        _.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {
            _.each(team, function(player) {
                var playerView = new PlayerView({model: player});
                this.$el.append(playerView.render().el);
            }, this);
        }, this);

        return this;

    },
```

Okay I think this is the only code I need to show to demonstrate what I am trying to figure out.

You can see all I am outputting is the `playerView` el looping through the collection. This is nice, but I need to add markup right after I loop the teams`_.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {`  and before I loop the players `_.each(team, function(player) {`

So that I can wrap the players inside a div with their like below.

```
_.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {
    <div class="<%= i %>">//Set this div here obviously 
                          //can't inside a render method.
                          //need to create a template for.
                          //this view or something.
        _.each(team, function(player) {
        var playerView = new PlayerView({model: player});
        this.$el.append(playerView.render().el);
        }, this);

    </div> // Close the sample div
           // wrapping my players collection.

}, this);
```

I could do this with one view by setting something like the above as a template and just rendering that single template, but since I am working with two views I am not sure how to add markup for teams? Does this make sense?

**Edit:** Just came to mind, but I am thinking I can instantiate `playerView` inside a template (not sure if possible will test) then render that template which would still include the single player view allowing me to interact with each model in the `playerView` like normal. I am not sure about this but just a thought, let's see ill post back asap.

**Edit:** Yeah the above doesn't work, you can't use javascript inside a underscore template for the obvious reasons, I am wondering if there is an underscore method to parse stuff inside the template as javascript IDK. Still hoping to find a good solution.

**My Solution:** First of all thanks to @fbynite for your solution, you were bold enough to share your solution I appreciate that, but it was a little more than I needed I think, what do I know?

I just played around a little and came up with this piece of code, it works well and only adds 2 to 3 extra lines to my existing code, so I don't have to re adjust my logic (I get confused easily!). The code below is an improvement of the code above "Players view for a collection of players (just the render method)" this is inside a render method for my `PlayersView`.

```
_.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {
    var teams = $('<div class="'+i+'"></div>')
    this.$el.append(teams);
    _.each(team, function(player) {
        var playerView = new PlayerView({model: player});
        this.$el.find('.'+i).append(playerView.render().el);
    }, this);
}, this);
```

This is so much easier for me, it's much more maintainable, the con about this code is I am not sure if its stable or could cause issues in the future, but it works well for now!

As you can tell I just create a div element with the team name as the class, then append it to the view's root element. Then after that is set, I loop through the players and append the `playerView` to it's respected class. Let me know if you smart people see any issues with that, I'd love to learn!!

Comment: Ask questions if you need to, I may have left out some key information. I just hope you get the general gist of what I mean. I can get as specific as your questions require.

Comment: Just FYI - a CSS class like `.2` is invalid - you probably want a prefix, e.g. `team-2`. Also, in your code above, there's no need to look for `this.$el.find('.'+i)` - you have access to the `teams` variable in the closure, so you can just use `teams.append(playerView.render().el)`. In fact, this would remove the need for the `i`-based class entirely.

Comment: It doesnt return a number. `i` returns the name of the team. Typically `i` is an integer, but I had help with this code and the helper used that argument, I could change it. The second part you talk about is interesting, okay thanks. I am not sure I understand because I need to wrap the players in that `i` div.

Comment: Oh, I see you put `teams` okay making that adjustment now.

Comment: Ah, right. Makes sense, though I'd still watch out for invalid classes (e.g. if the team name has spaces or non-word characters). Still, as noted, I don't think you need the special class at all - just refer to the `teams` variable.

Comment: Good I will. I made sure the teams are valid inside the json, but I will make sure to use `str.toLowerCase()` and should be okay in that department (knock on wood). Yeah so I forgot yes I can lowercase that `i` variable, so that's one step and ill make sure there are no spaces. Thanks for the insight your idea helped, it works great looks better and most likely preforms better.

Comment: You should be able to use `teams.append(playerView.render().el);`, instead of having to go `find` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could create a `documentFragment` to achieve the desired results such as:

```
render: function() {
  // Make the documentFragment a jQuery object for consistency.
  var $df = $(document.createDocumentFragment()),
      groupedPlayers = playersCollection.groupBy('team');

  _.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {
    var $div = $('<div>',{'class':i});
    $df.append($div);
    _.each(team, function(player) {
      var playerView = new PlayerView({model: player});
      $div.append(playerView.render().el);
    });
  });

 // populate the view's element with the documentFragment.
 this.$el.html($df);

 return this;

}
```

Comment: Cool, looks like a possible solution, won't count this out. Thanks for sharing that, I am going to leave this open a little longer in hopes to get a slightly better solution. Maybe this is a really good solution what do I know. Intuitively speaking it feels slightly unnatural from the backbone pattern.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry, I agree, it does feel unnatural. I added another approach as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, it looks good from what I see. Ill post back soon to let you know how it works. I bet it works great.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I think it may be more than I need, I wrote a little something that works, check the original post, feel free to critique it if you see any possible issues.

Comment: This works very similar to what I have above, but when I populate my localStorage it renders the player view double times, with both methods.. hmm I need to figure that out, but thanks for this.

Comment: Okay I figured out why it was rendering the players twice, silly mistake by me. I still went with my method, but the two are similar IMO, and this definitely helped.